# Is it safe to name an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

With Promises trending up, we often see this:

```
getSomeData.then(
        // success
    function(data) {
        ...
    },
        // failure
    function(error) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Those comments could be helpful to newbies, but I would much prefer to name the anonymous functions, like this:

```
getSomeData.then(
    function success(data) {
        ...
    },
    function failure(error) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Naming an anonymous function, in this case, makes sense, but is it safe? I've seen older posts here that reference [this article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements) as a warning about IE, but does anyone know if this is still an issue with IE9?

Comment: What do you mean/expect by "safe"?

Comment: If you name your function, then it's not anonymous anymore ;)

Comment: @Ian Safe = does not have any negative side effects like the bug in old IE.

Comment: @RobW That's how I took it, but since the OP seems to understand the possible problems, I wasn't sure of their point (other than if they're still problems in IE >= 9). I guess I was just wondering because the one (side effect) in your answer (about the expression being leaked) is the only problem from the included article that I could see actually being encountered.

Comment: @Ian Apparently the OP doesn't know whether the issue is still existent in the latest versions of IE, hence the question.

Comment: @RobW *sigh* nevermind...

Comment: It’s safe in IE9 and up, yes — but does it make sense? Swap the order, and it’s twice as confusing. I’d rather an object.

Comment: @minitech Good point about objects. You mean like `var handlers = { success: function () { }, failure: function () { } }; getSomeData.then(handlers.success, handlers.failure);` ?

Comment: @minitech Swapping would also be a problem for anonymous functions and outdated comments in general. By naming the functions, the writer conveys his intended meaning.

Comment: @RobW: I mean what Ian said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's safe <sup>1</sup> to use named function expressions. The bug you're mentioning does not exist in IE9 any more (it does in IE8 though).

Another advantage of the named expression is for debugging. Instead of `(anonymous)`, you will see a meaningful name.

<sup>1</sup>
For the ones who don't know: In Internet Explorer up to and including version 8, the named variable would leak in the following code:

```
var expressionName = function shouldNotLeak() {};
shouldNotLeak(); // Error in all browsers except for Internet Explorer <= 8
```

Comment: The culture of keeping compatibility with older browsers is rapidly dying. I used to have these old-browser-compatibilty requirements a lot a few year ago, but I haven´t had one client asking for IE8 compatibility in the last year!.

So my advice is: don´t be afraid of requiring the users to have an updated browser, but make your clients aware of the significance of this decision!.

Comment: **Another** advantage of named expressions is local recursion (where it doesn't leak) :)

Comment: @jacmkno the problem, sadly, is Windows XP since you cannot get above IE8. Of course you can use another browser. Far too many businesses are still using XP, including where I am.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant I can attest to `Far too many businesses are still using XP` - it really sucks having IE7/8 being our primary targets of development